# Changed hardware - why is the system freezing after start up?

Tags: windows-8.1, 64-bit

Urgent help required please...:(
I recently changed my motherboard, CPU, cooler and ram in my PC.  I used my same HDD that is running windows 8.1.  I can get the computer to boot up with all of my same desktop, icons and pictures, but after a few minutes, the screen freezes and the mouse and keyboard will not work and everything stops.  I have a 750W power supply  running 16Gb of ram and an AMD FX 9850 processor (with a deep cool CPU cooler on top).  Do I need to reinstall windows to make it work ?

I thought if you just plugged it all back in properly, it'd work fine, but to no avail.  I also bought extra thermal paste for the CPR/heat sync but it has made no difference, so overheating does not seem to be the issue.  Just about in tears !!!! Can anyone provide timely assistance ?

Many thanks

Adam

Comment: Reinstalling windows will probably fix your issues - but try reinstalling the chipset driver for your corresponding motherboard first. You can find it on the product page of your motherboard under 'support/software' in most cases.

Comment: Try also checking your RAM configuration in BIOS.... we had a similar problem and it turned out that the CL of the RAM needed reducing and our machines were stable again...

Answer (score 0):

The reasons for the error you are encountering are numerous. It might be a software issue as well as a harware issue.

Try to boot into a live system (e.g. Knoppix) via USB or DVD. If that does not freeze after some time, then it's most likely a software issue. If the live system freezes, too, then chances are good that it is a harware issue.

If it's a software issue, try to install the appropriate drivers for your new hardware starting with the motherboard's chipset drivers as proposed by benjaminS.

If it's a hardware issue, it might be related to an overheated CPU. Try some hardware monitor software (e.g. http://openhardwaremonitor.org/ or http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html) and check the CPU temperature.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have now noted that my new FX9590 AMD processor is 220W.  The motherboard supports up to a 140W.  Could it be that there is not enough power to the chip and it keeps crashing ?  I have looked at a few forums and they all seem to say this ?

Comment: Yes, this could definitely be the source for your problems. You could check with your motherboard manufacturer if they have a list of supported processors for your board.